# Warning al tratar de listar elementos de un array a través de una api conectada a mi bbdd

Tags: php, array, json, api

Recibo el siguiente warning al tratar de listar unas actividades a través de una api.

> Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\DAES\UF4\ACTIVIDAD\APPWEB\controladores\controladorActividades.php on line 94

El código de la función :

```
function listarActividades()
{

    //definimos a dónde nos vamos a conectar
    $endpoint = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/API/index.php";
    //inicializamos el curl
    $curl = curl_init();
    //le configuramos la url a la que se va a conectar, alojada en la var $endpoint
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    //esta opción chequea que si todo va bien devuelva 1
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    //ejecutamos pe y tición y la alojamos en var $output
    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    //cerramos la petición
    curl_close($curl);
    //decodificamos el jason de $output y lo metemos en un array
    $listado = json_decode($output, true);
    $actividades = array();

    foreach ($listado as $fila) {
        $actividad  new Actividad($fila["titulo"], $fila["fecha"], $fila["ciudad"], $fila["tipo"], $fila["coste"], $fila["usuario"],);
        array_push($actividades, $actividad);
    }

    return $actividades;
}
```

Estoy decodificando el formato json y convirtiéndolo en array que guardo en la variable $listado.

Contenido de las líneas 94, 95 y 96:

```
foreach ($listado as $fila) {
    $actividad = new Actividad($fila["titulo"], $fila["fecha"], $fila["ciudad"], $fila["tipo"], $fila["coste"], $fila["usuario"],);
    array_push($actividades, $actividad);
}
```

función e la API:

```
function listarActividades()
{

    global $conexion_mysql;

    $consulta = "SELECT *
                 FROM actividades 
                              
                 ";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion_mysql, $consulta);

    $actividades = array();

    if ($resultado) {

        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {

            array_push($actividades, $fila);
        }

        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        echo json_encode($actividades);
    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.1 500Internal Server Error");
    }

    return $actividades;
}
```

Esto es lo que devuelve la API:

```
[
  {
    "id": "48",
    "titulo": "lalala",
    "fecha": "2022-05-19",
    "ciudad": "post",
    "tipo": "Viajes",
    "coste": "1",
    "usuario": "luso"
  },
  {
    "id": "49",
    "titulo": "SEF",
    "fecha": "2021-12-17",
    "ciudad": "SEF",
    "tipo": "Copas",
    "coste": "0",
    "usuario": "romancch"
  },
  {
    "id": "51",
    "titulo": "post",
    "fecha": "2022-05-19",
    "ciudad": "post",
    "tipo": "Viajes",
    "coste": "0",
    "usuario": "pepe"
  },
  {
    "id": "52",
    "titulo": "QQQQ",
    "fecha": "2021-12-17",
    "ciudad": "GGGGG",
    "tipo": "Cultura",
    "coste": "0",
    "usuario": "luso"
  },
  {
    "id": "53",
    "titulo": "ppp",
    "fecha": "2021-12-16",
    "ciudad": "jjj",
    "tipo": "Música",
    "coste": "0",
    "usuario": "luso"
  }
]
```

Según creo ya le estoy pasando un array, y la información no es null, dónde está el problema??

ps: sorry por los valores random...

Comment: Deberías añadir comprobaciones para control de posibles errores. Por ejemplo: comprobar si $output es false, en tal caso recuperar error de curl, comprobar también si $output está vacío, comprobar código HTTP de respuesta si es 200, comprobar si $listado no es false, comprobar también si $listado es un array... El lado de la API también es mejorable en este sentido (controlar errores y devolver respuesta conforme a los mismos si se producen). Implementar todo eso te ayudará a depurar casos como el que estás teniendo ahora.

Comment: "Según crees" le estás pasando un array, pero es evidente que no. La máquina te está diciendo que le estás pasando null, y la máquina no se equivoca en eso, créeme. Haz un `var_dump` de `$listado` y lo verás. Después, querrás hacer un `var_dump` de `$output`, y finalmente te darás cuenta de que lo adecuado es añadir control de posibles errores como te he dicho en mi otro comentario ;)